# I can't login to Superset after docker installation

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I Installed Apache Superset through the docker installation and it requested to create an admin.

I can build the app and get to the landing page but the credentials I created do not work.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the other answers in Ubuntu 20.04 and had a to make a slight change, perhaps due to a newer version of Superset or because I am running the non-dev version.

After launching the non-dev environment with

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up -d
```

The default container name that you want in the non-dev environment is "superset_app"

```
$ docker exec -it superset_app bash
```

I'm not sure when or where this change was made, but the docker-init.sh script is now at /app/docker/docker-init.sh.

```
root@5c52fe612108:/app# docker/docker-init.sh
```

This script will do many things, including initialize the default admin:admin account and create the example database if SUPERSET_LOAD_EXAMPLES=yes was set in the .env-non-dev before the containers were built.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it's amazing that this very basic step is not found in the official docs (https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose) but I have to find it in a 2 year old stackoverflow answer with 0 votes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> superset-init

Ex -  docker exec -it superset superset-init
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run following command to setup username and password:
`docker-compose exec superset bash /app/docker-init.sh`

If you run it in windows you will get an error. To fix it first run following:
`dos2unix docker-init.sh`

This will make the script Linux ready as the script got copied from the windows system to a Linux one and it has certain special characters that throw errors.

Checkout the issue in GitHub as well:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/10149